# MySQL REGEXP string not followed by another

Tags: mysql, regex

In MySQL, I need to select all registers from a table containing a certain string in a field but not followed by another string.
I have tried using:

```
select * from table where field REGEXP "(desired_string(?non_desired_follow_up))"
```

However, I get:

```
Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

Can anyone help to get the right sentence for doing that?

Comment: MySQL regex does not support lookarounds, so you can't use `(?!.*non_desired_follow_up)`

Comment: You could try `field REGEXP "(desired_string)" and field NOT regexp "(desired_string(non_desired_follow_up))"` 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that option. However, that would skip fields containing both _desired_string_ and _desired_stringnon_desired_follow_up_ which I would like to also select

Comment: Sorry, some things are not practical in SQL.